# Cannot use any TypeScript features in VSCode in my pc

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I cannot use any TypeScript features in up-to-date VSCode (1.30.2) in my own pc.

Any project that has no problems before has the same problem now.

I think it must be my own pc problem, but I can't resolve it.

How can I deal with this problem?

I tried this steps but the problem still exists:

- Launch `code --disable-extensions` then open `.ts` file
- Rename `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code`
- Rename `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`
- Downgrade VSCode to 1.29.1
- Rename `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- Using insiders build

I tried to install a very pure insiders build of VSCode, did not install any extensions, and created a pure node project, but the problem still exists.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrsW7.png)

Like the screenshot, every times when I click the version of TypeScript at the status bar, an error happens.

Error notification info:

```
Running the contributed command:'typescript.selectTypeScriptVersion' failed.
```

The full error log (In "Log (Extension Host)") after the version clicked:

```
[2019-01-14 19:51:28.132] [exthost] [error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceClient' of undefined
    at t.SelectTypeScriptVersionCommand.execute (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\typescript-language-features\dist\extension.js:1:56782)
    at e._executeContributedCommand (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:484:455)
    at e.$executeContributedCommand (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:485:6)
    at t._doInvokeHandler (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:639:202)
    at t._invokeHandler (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:638:862)
    at t._receiveRequest (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:637:477)
    at t._receiveOneMessage (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:636:299)
    at c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:634:81
    at c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:38:994
    at e.fire (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:44:76)
    at a (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:169:881)
    at Socket.f._socketDataListener (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\node\extensionHostProcess.js:170:95)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:279:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:636:20) typescript.selectTypeScriptVersion
```

VSCode Insiders info:

```
Version: 1.31.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: 2ab82c12ed809fd1df921d016eed344a18a9ee8f
Date: 2019-01-14T06:18:47.017Z
Electron: 3.0.13
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

VSCode Stable info:

```
Version: 1.30.2 (user setup)
Commit: 61122f88f0bf01e2ac16bdb9e1bc4571755f5bd8
Date: 2019-01-07T22:54:13.295Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

System info:

```
OS Name:    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version: 10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
node -v:    v10.14.2
npm -v:     v6.4.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, it's my bad.

I tried `Developer: Toggle Shared Process` then I found the problem: I set an incorrect value for the system variable `%TEMP%`, it should be `D:\Temp` but I set `D;\Temp`.

Some `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory` was printed in developer tools console, it shows that VSCode tried to access some wrong paths.

Now I fixed the `%TEMP%` variable, the problem solved.

When the `%TEMP%` variable is invalid, VSCode cannot even install any extensions.